# Spring boot security 403 status code in angular request

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I already have the spring boot security configuration to create JWT token (Authentication & Authorization) the token creation and validation works fine using POSTMAN but using a post request from rest client (angular 8) the response is the next:

POST http://localhost:8080/users/login 403

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/users/login", ok: false, …}

This is the spring configuration

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/employee/save").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(this.getAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager() ,env));
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception{
        AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
        return filter;
    }

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

And this is the angular request

```
this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.userName,this.loginForm.value.password)
.subscribe(response=>{
       
     });
```

Service

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/login', {'userName':userName, 'password':password});
```

Comment: You got status code `403` and status text `OK`, this is weird.

Comment: for `this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.userName,this.loginForm.value.password)
.subscribe(response=>{` that line, what happends if i write `response=>console.log(response)` instead of `response` can you show us the response?

Comment: It's giving me the same error POST http://localhost:8080/users/login 403

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/users/login", ok: false, …}